# Свои Лайки на Сайте РНР

Tags: php, mysql

Как сделать свои лайки на сайте(как в ВК)? Допустим есть столбец like в таблице news, как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на лайк, добовлялся 1 балл в столбец

Comment: AJAX-запрос отправлять, далее как обычно PHP.

Comment: через ajax 下t запрос

Answer (score 3):

Столбец `like` в таблице `news` - на мой взгляд не совсем удачная схема. Вам наверняка ведь важно **кто** поставил данный лайк, и вам наверняка важно, чтобы **один и тот же пользователь не смог поставить лайк дважды**. На мой взгляд, будет рациональным сделать таблицу `likes`, у которой будет связь с пользователем (у вас в системе ведь есть таблица `users`?) и связь с вашей новостью. То есть в таблице `likes` должны быть колонки `news_item_id, user_id`. Авторизованный пользователь сможет делать запросы на сервер (например при помощи AJAX), а сервер будет проверять - не поставлен ли уже лайк (нет ли у новости лайка от данного пользователя). Если нет - добавлять в таблицу лайков новую запись (id новости и id пользователя). Есть еще вариант - в одном поле likes держать ID'ы пользователей, которые поставили лайк, в одной строчке (через запятую), но имхо это не очень правильный подход. Короче говоря, суть примерно такая:

- Есть таблицы `users`, `news`, `news_likes`
- При авторизации в вашей системе (логин-пароль), пользователь получает ID из таблицы `users`, (этот ID обычно помещается в сессию, массив $_SESSION)
- Когда пользователь кликает по кнопке/ссыкле/иконке лайка, происходит запрос на сервер (AJAX)
- В запросе передается ID новости, лайк к которой нужно поставить
- PHP скрипт, который обрабатывает ваш запрос, получает ID новости ($_GET или $_POST), затем достает из сессии ID текущего пользователя и делает запрос к базе (что-то типа `SELECT COUNT (*) FROM news_likes WHERE news_id = id_новости AND user_id = id_пользователя`). Если кол-во больше ноля - значит лайк уже стоит и его ставить не нужно. В противном случае делается запрос на вставку новой записи в таблицу news_likes
- Скрипт возвращает какое-то значение сигнализирующее об успехе (чтобы вы могли как-то отреагировать на стороне клиента, например пометить кнопку не активной или что-то подобное)

При выводе списка новостей можно делать запросы на кол-во лайков, чтобы показывать сколько их, либо можно хранить актуальное кол-во в поле новости (что-то вроде likes_count) и показывать его (поле нужно будет обновлять всякий раз при изменении кол-ва, но при выводе это оптимальнее, меньше запросов).

Как-то так..